# Installing rmagick gem on Windows 8 x64 for Ruby 2.0 x64

Tags: windows-8, imagemagick, rmagick, ruby-2.0

I'm trying to install Rmagick gem on Windows 8, Ruby 2.0 - all with 64-bit flavour.
I installed Ruby 2.0 with RubyInstaller - version 2.0.0p247, installed DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224 on top. Then I installed ImageMagic - ImageMagick-6.8.6-4-Q16-x64-dll version, to be exact, with developer headers of course. All are directly on C: drive in respective subfolders without spaces in the names.
Then I try to build a gem.

```
gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=c:/ImageMagi
```

ck-6.8.6-Q16/lib --with-opt-include=c:/ImageMagick-6.8.6-Q16/include

the output is

```
    Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:430:in `try_do': The compiler failed to ge
nerate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:561:in `try_cpp'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1040:in `block in have_header
'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:891:in `block in checking_for
'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `block (2 levels) in p
ostpone'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:306:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `block in postpone'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:306:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:332:in `postpone'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:890:in `checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1039:in `have_header'
        from extconf.rb:194:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rmagi
ck-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/ext/RMa
gick/gem_make.out
```

However i think the problem is not in stdint.h file. I then check a content of file

> c:\Ruby200-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\rmagick-2.13.2\ext\RMagick\

Which is

```
    checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... -------------------- yes

--------------------

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -Ic:/ImageMagick-6.8.6-Q16/include -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby200-x64/lib -Lc:/ImageMagick-6.8.6-Q16/lib -L.    -lCORE_RL_magick_ -lX11  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby200  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
c:/devkit-x64/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/ImageMagick-6.8.6-Q16/lib/X11.lib when searching for -lX11
c:/devkit-x64/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/ImageMagick-6.8.6-Q16/lib/X11.lib when searching for -lX11
c:/devkit-x64/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/ImageMagick-6.8.6-Q16/lib\X11.lib when searching for -lX11
c:/devkit-x64/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lX11
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */
```

which looks like a problem with X11.lib file. It is, of course, located in ImageMagick lib folder, it has a date of 2009, and I have no idea what to do next or what to think about this.
As I'm working with a large files - 6000x6000 pixels I would love to use 64bit versions wherether possible.

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same problem.  Using Ruby 2.0.0p247 and gem 2.0.7 with ImageMagick 6.8.6

I have tried with the 32 bit and the 64 bit version of ImageMagick.  In both cases, the terminal output is the same:

```
$ gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-dir=/c/ImageMagick64
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-opt-dir=c:/ImageMagick64'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    c:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-opt-dir=c:/ImageMagick64
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=c:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby
c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:430:in `try_do': The compiler failed to ge
nerate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:561:in `try_cpp'
        from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1040:in `block in have_header
'
        from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:891:in `block in checking_for
'
        from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `block (2 levels) in p
ostpone'
        from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:306:in `open'
        from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `block in postpone'
        from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:306:in `open'
        from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:332:in `postpone'
        from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:890:in `checking_for'
        from c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1039:in `have_header'
        from extconf.rb:194:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rmagi
ck-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/ext/RMa
gick/gem_make.out
```

However, when I use the 32 bit version, the mkmf.log file gives me an error for both CORE_RL_magick_.lib AND X11.lib (incompatible version).  When I use the 64 bit version, I only get an error on X11.lib.

This leads me to believe that the X11.lib is bad, maybe a 32 bit version included with their distribution.

My mkmf.log file is as follows:

```
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... -------------------- yes

--------------------

"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -Ic:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/x64-mingw32 -Ic:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -Ic:/Ruby200-x64/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -Ic:/ImageMagick64/include -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c  -L. -Lc:/Ruby200-x64/lib -Lc:/ImageMagick64/lib -L.    -lCORE_RL_magick_ -lX11  -lx64-msvcrt-ruby200  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
c:/ruby200-x64/rubydevkit/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/ImageMagick64/lib/X11.lib when searching for -lX11
c:/ruby200-x64/rubydevkit/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/ImageMagick64/lib/X11.lib when searching for -lX11
c:/ruby200-x64/rubydevkit/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible c:/ImageMagick64/lib\X11.lib when searching for -lX11
c:/ruby200-x64/rubydevkit/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lX11
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */
```

---

I know it doesn't necessarily answer the question, but I was able to get the gem built by using the 32 bit version of ruby with the 32 bit ImageMagick library - it "Just Works"

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a mismatch between versions:

> Ruby x64 will only be able to compile and install rmagick x64
>
> Ruby x86 (32 bit) will only be able to compile and install rmagick x86

Make sure that you install same version of both.